# How to adjust a Scrollview's height and width to fit in multiple screen resolutions

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

as the title say's it, I have Problems with scaling my Scrollview.

The Scrollview contains multiple Buttons.
I tested my app on a Google Pixel 3 XL, on which it Looks fine , but on a Pixel 2 it Looks too big and some Buttons aren't reachable , because the Navigation bar vovers them.

Here's my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="723dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.285"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="504dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="504dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="196dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/DarkGrey"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.531"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try using a `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` inside ScrollView

Comment: using a LinearLayout didn't helped. All my Buttons (except my first two) where placed outside the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **dimens** values in your project and give the proper **padding** to each object whether it's a button,text or anything.

create a dimens.xml folder and add this and add those values according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="_minus1sdp">-1.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus2sdp">-2.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus3sdp">-3.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus4sdp">-4.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus5sdp">-5.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus6sdp">-6.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus7sdp">-7.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus8sdp">-8.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus9sdp">-9.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus10sdp">-10.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus11sdp">-11.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus12sdp">-12.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus13sdp">-13.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus14sdp">-14.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus15sdp">-15.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus16sdp">-16.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus17sdp">-17.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus18sdp">-18.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus19sdp">-19.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus20sdp">-20.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus21sdp">-21.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus22sdp">-22.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus23sdp">-23.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus24sdp">-24.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus25sdp">-25.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus26sdp">-26.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus27sdp">-27.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus28sdp">-28.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus29sdp">-29.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus30sdp">-30.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus31sdp">-31.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus32sdp">-32.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus33sdp">-33.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus34sdp">-34.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus35sdp">-35.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus36sdp">-36.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus37sdp">-37.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus38sdp">-38.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus39sdp">-39.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus40sdp">-40.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus41sdp">-41.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus42sdp">-42.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus43sdp">-43.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus44sdp">-44.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus45sdp">-45.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus46sdp">-46.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus47sdp">-47.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus48sdp">-48.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus49sdp">-49.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus50sdp">-50.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus51sdp">-51.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus52sdp">-52.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus53sdp">-53.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus54sdp">-54.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus55sdp">-55.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus56sdp">-56.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus57sdp">-57.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus58sdp">-58.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus59sdp">-59.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="_minus60sdp">-60.00dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

For more Information you can refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

It will guide you through different screen size support.